# Batch Programming, Error Handling, and Start Command

Tags: error-handling, batch-file

I am just starting to learn how to script. I'm trying to understand how the system handles Error Levels and how they can be used in error handling. I know there is a difference between the environment variable %ERRORLEVEL% and the Error Level of the system. If I understand this correctly, then the
`If ERRORLEVEL 1`
code would check the environment variable before it checks the error level of the previous command.

So, in my program I am trying to interface a startup/stop script that will start/stop all scripts of a given machine (for testing I'm just using one application notepad.exe as an example). I have two wrapper scripts that will either start up or stop the applications by passing arguments to the independent script. If there is an error in the independent script, it will set the errorlevel using the
`EXIT /B n`

command. Once control is returned to the calling script, it will go to an error handling script if the exit status is non-zero.

At first I was setting the %ERRORLEVEL% to zero manually and then testing for an error after a START or TASKKILL command. But then I read that clearing %ERRORLEVEL% with
`SET ERRORLEVEL=`
is a better method. My issue comes in when I try to start the app with

```
START "" notepad.exe
```

Whenever I test the errorlevel after this command it is always greater than or equal to 1 unless I use SET ERRORLEVEL=0 before I run the start command. I have inserted the code for the four scripts below. Any insight and advice would be greatly appreciated.

appstart.bat:

```
@echo off
:: Script for application Start
set ERRORLEVEL=
:: ****
:: Additional Batch files will be executed from within this file
:: Example: 
::     Call Appbat01.bat
:: The called batch file should set ERRORLEVEL non-zero if error
:: ****

call test.bat -start
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (call error.bat) 
echo.
echo Control was returned to appstart.bat...
:: **** End Calls
goto end

:end
```

appstop.bat:

```
@echo off
:: Script for application Start
set ERRORLEVEL=
:: ****
:: Additional Batch files will be executed from within this file
:: Example: 
::     Call Appbat01.ba
:: The called batch file should set ERRORLEVEL non-zero if error
:: ****

call test.bat -stop
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (call error.bat) 
echo.
echo Control was returned to appstop.bat...
:: **** End Calls
goto end

:end
```

test.bat:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="-start" goto :start
if "%1"=="-stop" goto :stop
goto wrongParams

:start
::****
:: Insert start up stripts here...
:: If there is an error, set ERRORLEVEL=1
::****
    set ERRORLEVEL=0
    echo.
    echo ********
    echo starting the service...
    echo.
    ::start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\office11\winword.exe"
    start notepad.exe
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
    qprocess notepad.exe
    echo *Start.success* ERRORLEVEL is: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
    goto end

:stop
::****
:: Insert stopping stripts here...
:: If there is an error, set ERRORLEVEL>1
::****
    set ERRORLEVEL=0
    echo.
    echo ********
    echo stopping the service...
    echo.
    qprocess notepad.exe 
    taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto noProcess
    goto end

:noProcess
    set ERRORLEVEL=2
    echo *noProcess* ERRORLEVEL is now: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
    exit /b 2
:error
:: Errorhandler. Log application status and cause of error here. Set
:: ERRORLEVEL > 1 before returning to caller. 
    set ERRORLEVEL=1
    echo.
    echo **** Error handler inside test.bat ****
    echo.
    echo *error* ERRORLEVEL is now: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
    exit /b 1

:wrongParams
:: Output an error if the wrong parameters were passed to this script.
:: Maybe try to self correct the parameter...
    set ERRORLEVEL=1
    echo.
    echo '%1' is an invalid parameter.
    echo Usage: %0 [-stop ^| -start] 
    echo *wrongParams* ERRORLEVEL is now: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
    exit /b 1
:end
```

error.bat:

```
@echo off
echo **** You have reached error.bat ****
echo ERRORLEVEL inside of error.bat is: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo.
::*** Handle error...***
goto error%ERRORLEVEL%

:error2
    echo The process could not be stopped for some reason.
    goto end
:error1
    echo The process had an error in start up.
::***                ***
    goto end

:end
```

Comment: If you are running the code, this is where I get an error. If I use start, it fires up notepad just fine without any errors. If I use stop, it stops notepad without any errors. If I use stop again, it throws an error as expected. Now, if I use start, it should start up notepad without any errors again. However, the if statement after the START command is true and it goes to an error. I'm not sure why this is happening. Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should never SET the %errorlevel% variable.  You are correct that there is a difference; The errorlevel that you get from an exiting process is an internal register that you can read with the %errorlevel% syntax.  However, if you create a variable named ERRORLEVEL, it will mask the internal register and you lose access to the exit codes.

If you need to set the errorlevel register to a specific value, you can do it with the following command:

```
%comspec% /c exit %value%
```

This will spawn a process which immediately exits with the desired code.

Comment: Fantastic! I have been able to run the scripts without any unexpected errors. I tried not setting the ERRORLEVEL directly before, but I couldn't get it to reset before I ran the next command. But now I set the ERRORLEVEL back to zero using the command you gave in the error.bat script after it finishes doing the error handling.