# How to find a certain word in a file without using ERRORLEVEL (batch)

Tags: batch-file, findstr, errorlevel

I can use ERRORLEVEL, but tried and with a loop it failed.
I am writing a batch "shell."
Since I have tried and tried, I am finally asking for help.
The reason I don't want to use errorlevel is because the loop.

**(FULL) SHELL**

```
@set /p build=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\WellOS\Build".txt
@title WellOS V.%build%
@echo off
goto boot
:register
cls
echo You are registering...
echo If this is an error press CTRL + C NOW...
pause
cls
set /p user= Enter your username: 
set /p passwordreg= Enter your password: 
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%"
mkdir "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\Documents"
echo %passwordreg% >"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\password".txt
echo 2 >"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\OSfiles\bootset".txt
echo Your done.
pause
goto welloslog
:booterror
echo Sorry the boot file has an error. Check the user manual for BOOT$
pause
:boot
set /p boot=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\OSfiles\bootset".txt
if %boot% == 1 goto register
if %boot% == 2 goto welloslog
goto booterror
cls
:ERROR
cls
echo ----------ERROR-------------------
echo %error%
pause
goto %back%
:welloslog
cls
echo Welcome to WellOS2!
echo ----------------LOGIN-------------
set /p user= Username: 
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%" goto pass
set error= Sorry that account doesn't exist.
set back=welloslog
goto welloslogerror
:pass
set /p password=<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Users\%user%\password".txt
set /p passwordlog= Password: 
if /i %passwordlog% == %password% goto wellos
set error= Sorry! wrong password.
set back= welloslog
goto error
:wellos
cls
:wellosnocls
echo --------------MAIN---------------
echo type help for help
set /p command= #: 
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.sys" set type=sys
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.pro" set type=pro
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.sys" goto po
if exist "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.pro" goto po
set error= !Unreconized program/system program!
set back=wellos
goto error
:po
set lines=0
echo --------------%command%.%type%---------------
:porep
set /a lines=%lines% + 1
set /p "code="<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.%type%\%command%.%type%-%lines%".wellcode
if "%code%"=="GOWELL" goto wellosnocls
findstr /I /L "if" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.%type%\%command%.%type%-%lines%.wellcode"
:skip
call %code%
goto porep
::Tools
:iftl
%code%
goto porep
```

**PROGRAM OPENER (What I am talking about, and having problems with...)**

```
:po
set lines=0
echo --------------%command%.%type%---------------
:porep
set /a lines=%lines% + 1
set /p "code="<"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.%type%\%command%.%type%-%lines%".wellcode
if "%code%"=="GOWELL" goto wellosnocls
findstr /I /L "if" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\WellOS2\Programdata\%command%.%type%\%command%.%type%-%lines%.wellcode" goto iftl
:skip
call %code%
goto porep
::Tools
:iftl
%code%
goto porep
```

Comment: Why should `ErrorLevel` not be possible? `find`/`findstr` (re-)set it if a/no match is found, so whan querying immediately afterwards, it will give the result; if you query `ErrorLevel` in a loop/block, use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use `!ErrorLevel!` rather than `%ErrorLevel%`... alternatively check whether or not the output of `find`/`findstr` is (not) empty, by parsing it with `for /F`, for instance...

Comment: Almost anything you run is going to set `ERRORLEVEL`, even if it just sets it to 0 to indicate success.  If you must preserve it, then your best bet is to save it to a variable, run your commands, and then restore it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498460/batch-programming-error-handling-and-start-command/6527436#6527436

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you were using `%errorlevel%` inside of a loop when you should have been using `!errorlevel!`.

Comment: You having problems with your code, but where and what type of problems? From your _detailed_ description, my best answer is that there must be a bug in your code

Comment: By the line `findstr /I /L "if" "C:\*\*.wellcode" goto iftl` in the _program opener_, you want to do `goto iftl` in case a match is found? if so, just place `&&` before `goto iftl`; see also my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34302735/5047996)...

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr "targetstring" datafilename >flagfilename
for %%a in (flagfilename) do if %%~za==0 echo not found
for %%a in (flagfilename) do if %%~za neq 0 echo found
```

beyond that, your question is too vague.

Comment: I don't get  the `datafilename >flagfilename` part of the first line.

Comment: I have no idea what your datafile name is. You'd need to substitute it in here. You can use any name as a flagfile. This will be a file that will be created with a size of 0 or non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

The following command returns all lines of a text file `textfile.txt` that contain the word `word` (remove the `/I` switch if you want the search to be case-sensitive):

```
findstr /I /L "word" "textfile.txt"
```

With `for /F` you can capture the output and test whether it is empty, as the loop does not iterate if no match is encountered:

```
set "FOUND="
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    findstr /I /L "word" "textfile.txt"
') do (
    set "FOUND=Yes"
)
if defined FOUND (
    echo One or more matches found.
    rem do something...
) else (
    echo No match found.
    rem do something else...
)
```

Type `for /?` and `if /?` in command prompt to get details about the used commands.

---

There is also a way to use `ErrorLevel` implicitly, meaning you do not have to query its value by something like `%ErrorLevel%`, `!ErrorLevel!` or `if ErrorLevel`, namely when using conditional command separators:

- the `&&` separator executes the following command only in case the previous one succeeded, that is, it returned an `ErrorLevel` of `0`; (`findstr` returns `0` in case a match is encountered;)
- the `||` separator executes the following command only in case the previous one failed, that is, it returned an `ErrorLevel` other than `0`; (`findstr` returns a non-zero `ErrorLevel` in case no match is encountered;)

The following line of code demonstrates the usage:

```
findstr /I /L "word" "textfile.txt" && (echo One or more matches found.) || echo (No match found.)
```